# What is wrong with this Xhtml code using ul

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to validate the following xhtml code on validator.w3.org

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Let us try the use of heading styles
-->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Headings</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Program Pool</h1>
<h2>
<ul>
<li> Basic Programming </li>
<li> Intermediate Programming </li>
<li> Advanced Programming </li>
<li> Modular Programming </li>
</ul>
<!-- <br /> <br /> <br /> -->
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm receiving an error on line 17 (The line where the first ul tag appears). The main problem is the ul tag although the same syntax was accepted in other code I wrote. So what is wrong here?

Comment: Saying you have some error without showing the actual error is not really helpful.

Comment: ??? `<? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` and its no valid to put   `<ul>` inside a `<h*>` tag

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `h2` tag as a block-level element; it's a heading tag, and it functions the same as your `h1` tag above. Move the `</h2>` closing tag up and add some text:

```
<h2>Some Random Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolves if you just remove "`<H2>`" tag, used around the `<UL>` tag.

Use CSS for styling your UL if this need attention.

either remove  tag around or Give appropriate heading and close right there:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Let us try the use of heading styles
-->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Headings</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Program Pool</h1>
<ul>
<li> Basic Programming </li>
<li> Intermediate Programming </li>
<li> Advanced Programming </li>
<li> Modular Programming </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

OR

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Let us try the use of heading styles
-->
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> Headings</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Program Pool</h1>
**<h2>heading</h2>**
<ul>
<li> Basic Programming </li>
<li> Intermediate Programming </li>
<li> Advanced Programming </li>
<li> Modular Programming </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```